# Индивидуальный обработчик нажатия ENTER для каждой формы

Tags: jquery

У меня две формы, в каждой из них есть обработчик события по нажатию на клавишу "enter".

Вот код, который выполняется при нажатии на "enter" в первой форме:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode==13){
        alert('23');
    }
});
```

Вот код, который выполняется при нажатии на "enter" во второй форме:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode==13){
        alert('13');
    }
});
```

При нажатии на "enter" первый раз все отрабатывает корректно, во второй отрабатывает сначала событие для первой формы , а потом для второй(т.е. сначала выводит 23, затем 13).
(расположение функций с формами в коде соответствующее).

Как сделать так, чтобы событие нажатия на клавишу отлавливалось только 1 раз, в той функции, в которую я его записала?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы "слушаете" события `document`.
Используйте конкретную форму или элемент формы или проверяйте `id` формы(в случае через `document`).

```js
$("#form1").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('23');
  }
});

$("#form2").keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode==13){
        alert('13');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <h2>FORM 1</h2>
  <input type="test" name="test" value="test1">
</form>
<hr />
<form id="form2">
  <h2>FORM 2</h2>
  <input type="test" name="test2" value="test2">
</form>
```